# Using REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, regular-expression

Am trying to use backreference expression to take out three subexpressions from a search, and reposition each subexpression as follows:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('AAA 123 ppp','(^[[:alpha:]]+) ([[:digit:]]) ([[:alpha:]]+)','\3 \1 \2') from dual
```

However am getting the result as AAA 123 ppp where expecting ppp AAA 123
Where am i getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `+` after `[[:digit:]]`

```
select  regexp_replace('AAA 123 ppp','(^[[:alpha:]]+) ([[:digit:]]+) ([[:alpha:]]+)','\3 \1 \2') 
from    dual
```

> ppp AAA 123